# want to array multiplication in N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have JSON like below

```
{
  "_type": "Usage",
  "bids": [
    {
     "bid": 0.015,
      "clicks": 13,
      "endTime": "2016-06-01T00:31:39.000Z",
     },
    {
      "bid": 0.023,
      "clicks": 1731,
      "endTime": "2016-06-01T03:08:30.000Z",
     },
    {
      "bid": 0.025,
      "clicks": 604,
      "endTime": null,
     }
  ],
  "campaignId": 2229,
}
```

I want to multiplication of clicks and bid inside of bids But when I run below query its result is null **ARRAY_SUM( ( bids[`*`].clicks )*(bids[`*`].bid))**

```
select campaignId,ARRAY_MAX(bids[*].startTime) date,
```

`ARRAY_SUM(bids[*].clicks) clicks,ARRAY_SUM((bids[*].clicks)*(bids[*].bid)) total`

```
from Default where _type="DailyCampaignUsage";
```

But Total coming NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to multiply individual clicks/bid values for each element of the array. Note that bids[*].clicks produces an array of clicks values, and '*' is multiplication operator for basic/scalar data types. So, try this:

```
SELECT campaignId,ARRAY_MAX(bids[*].endTime) date,
       ARRAY_SUM(bids[*].clicks) clicks, 
       ARRAY_SUM(ARRAY x.clicks * x.bid FOR x IN bids END) total
FROM default
WHERE _type="DailyCampaignUsage";
```

-prasad